# Is it possible to alias paths for contextually generated page views?

Tags: views, 8, path-aliases

I have a content type with a path pattern (*[category]/[english_title]*) that is generated based on its field values.
In the node's page there is a block with referencing news items and a count based more link to a page with more news items.The path generated from the more link is the same as the node's alias but with /news appended to it (*[category]/[english_title]/news*).

For that I passed the English title as token through a hook to the more link which was fetched from the page side as an argument to be matched against. It was fine until I had some fields with special characters, especially titles with apostrophes of possessive 'S's. I am unsure about how to proceed. An easier way would be since there. There is already a news section to do something like /news?nid, but it got me thinking.

Is it possible to alias contextually generated views pages or substitute an already patterned portion of a URL with its alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the use scenario behind the [Sub-pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto). In your scenario, you're creating a "more link" page View with a */node/%/news* path and a contextual filter for the NID to retrieve that specific node's contextual news view. With the sub-pathauto module installed, that page view should be viewable via `[category]/[english_title]/news` alias.

Comment: This works so well for my use case that I feel stupid for not knowing about it.